# How to access ubuntu server using just hostname and not hostaname.local

Tags: 16.04, server, hostname

I have a ubuntu-Server 16.04 LTS running and fully updated. I can access it through **IP Address** and **hostname.local**, but if I try to access it with just **hostname** it can't reach the address. 
`hostname` and `host` files are properly configure.

**Details about My hosts:**

- ubuntu-server 16.04 (lets call it **ubuntuserver** for better
  undestanding);
- ubuntu 17.10 (called **ubuntudesktop**);
- windows (called **firstwin**);
- windows (called **secondwin**).

Note that I can ping ubuntudesktop with just the hostname with any Operating System

Comment: How do you trying to get access to server? by ssh? Does the server responding on pings when you trying to ping it by hostname?

Comment: Not just SSH, I use this server for media, database and backup. I have two machines with windows and one ubuntu. With ubuntu I can Access it using hostname.local and IP. On windows only IP works

Answer (score 0):

If you want the hostname and hostname.local to be resolved, and you use linux to access hostname, you have to add

```
search local
```

in your /etc/resolv.conf file. I am not sure how you do that if resolv.conf is generated. However, take a look at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html, where you can see directives for resolv.conf file.

You should always add your domain(s) with `search` if you want that also short names would be resolved correctly. If you computer is also in the same domain you can also use `domain` keyword. Since your top domain is local you do not have to change `ndots` option.

Probably the simplest way to make this work is to name your computer from where you try to access `hostname` to be `yourcomputer.local`. In that way, `local` will automatically be considered as your domain and both (`hostname` and `hostname.local`) will be resolved.

You did not give enough detail, what OS are you using to access hostname and how do you want to access it.

Comment: I've added more information on the problem I hope helps

Comment: I use both Linux and Windows to access

Answer (score 0):

You have configured hostname and hosts on your server only. In this case only server knows it's hostname.

For access to this server by it's hostname your should have properly configured DNS records or records in hosts file **on your computer** (for correct resolving hostname to IP address).

Comment: I have an application running on this server as well accessed by smartphone, windows and a ubuntu machine. This doesn't seems to be the right approach. As I said before I can access it with hostname.local and not just hostname